# mysql join with precedence

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to make a join in mysql so that the values from the right table are returned if and only if the corresponding values in the left table don't exist?

For example

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT userid,status FROM date_status WHERE date='20-03-2012') ds
JOIN 
    (SELECT userid,status FROM default_weekday_status WHERE day='tuesday') dws
ON
    ds.userid=dws.userid
```

I would like this to return `date_status.status` if the row in date_status exists, but `default_weekday_status.status` otherwise.

(Note that 20-03-2012 is a Tuesday and no, `tuesday` wouldn't be stored as a string ;-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the COALESCE function. I will return the first not-null value in the list of parameters.

```
SELECT coalesce(ds.status,dws.status) as status FROM
    date_status ds
RIGHT JOIN 
    default_weekday_status dws
ON
    ds.userid=dws.userid
WHERE
    ds.date='20-03-2012' or dws.day='tuesday'
```

The sub-queries have been removed, as they aren't very efficient.

[MySQL - COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: But +1 on removing the subqueries ;]

Answer (score 3):

Use a [RIGHT OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to select all the values from the right table, even if there is no value for the left table.

Now use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to get the ds.value, and when the value is NULL, get the dws.value:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ds.value,dws.value) FROM
    (SELECT userid,status FROM date_status WHERE date='20-03-2012') ds
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT userid,status FROM default_weekday_status WHERE day='tuesday') dws
ON
    ds.userid=dws.userid
```

P.S.: a RIGHT OUTER JOIN is just a LEFT JOIN with the tables in the inverse order...